# How to get the home/work address from android maps 2 sdk

Tags: android, sdk, maps, android-maps-v2

When I go maps|settings|edit home or work I see my home & work address, cool!

Anybody know how to get that same information from the Android SDK? I am working on a maps app and would like to plot those to points of reference, with out asking the user for them again?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this is possible, as it would be a serious privacy hole.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use reverse geocoding to convert the latitude/longitude into an address.  More info about geocoding can be found [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

Here is an example:

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());   
    String result = null;
    try {
        List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            Address address = list.get(0);
            // sending back first address line and locality
            result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
    }
```

Comment: The Geocoder is not quite what I need, at first. I need to get the default home and work address from the address book or where ever Google store it. Then I will use geoCoder to convert that address to lat/lon